# Facebook login is redirecting to logout page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have set up a Facebook login for my app and it works but what I don't know how to do is when you log in the app through Facebook, the app should take you to a menu screen that I have created in a view controller. Right now with Facebook login it is taking me to the log out page. Any help would be appreciated.

In my ViewController:-

```
         - (void)viewDidLoad{
               [super viewDidLoad];
               FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
               loginButton.readPermissions = @ [@"public_profile", @"email",  @"user_friends"];
               [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
               if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Cell" sender:self];
             }
}
```

I am checking if the user is logged in, and if yes perform the segue nothing happens.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: its all split in different files. But to summarise all I have created is the fb login and I have not used the interface builder. I need a way to link this to another ViewController when I log in. @Fogmeister

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is scattered across files. Without the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) answering this would be "guessing".

Comment: There are [plenty of tutorials out there](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=facebook+login+ios+tutorial+objective+c). Look up anyone of them and if the problem persists, come back with your code.

Comment: "Right now with facebook login it is taking me to the log out page" share screenshot of the page.

Answer (score 0):

When your facebook request complete the authentication process, the FB button is automatically turned into "log-out" mode since that is the next option for the user. To transition to a new view controller you can call a segue in the delegate method as shown below. This method will be called at the end of the FB credentialing, if you have subscribed to the delegate `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate`:

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton*)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult*)result

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have implemented your solution but when I log on it still automatically takes me the log out mode/page

Comment: can you post you code? Does the delegate method get called? I would put an NSlog in the delegate and make sure that the delegate method is called properly.